# Capturing Windows Users Session Switch event for all Users?

Tags: c#

I am making a Windows Desktop Application that will run only one instance per machine. Once it gets started **I need to get notified anytime a user logs in even if it was a session unlock?** 
The SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event captures only the session switch for the user that started the application while I need to capture the events for all users.

Comment: You'll probably have to split your system into two parts - one which runs with high permissions as a service and monitors global events, and the other being the actual application.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Is it a Windows Service? If its not, the program is not going to be running in the same session and you won't have access to that info.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know i have an option of making a windows service and a windows application but i need to keep this as simple as possible

Comment: @DavidP so is there any other way even if elevating the application privs or running it for all users somehow?

Comment: No way to run for all users, even with elevated privs. Use the Service as hofmeister suggests.

Comment: Your question ironically answered my question.  I was looking to see if I needed to isolate the events for other users, but it sounds like you weren't getting them as long as it's running within a user's context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use a [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/y817hyb6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which executes before a user logged in, into your system, to capture all events. After that notify your application about the changes. I use following approach.

1. Catch the different events with an [ServiceBase.OnSessionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange(v=vs.100).aspx) event handler.
2. Get the associated user information from the `SessionId` in [SessionChangeDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.serviceprocess.sessionchangedescription(v=vs.100).aspx) struct, from the `wtsapi32` and the [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32/WTSQuerySessionInformation.html) method.

I added the basic parts of this implementation below.

```
public class CustomService : ServiceBase
    protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription desc)
    {
        switch (desc.Reason)
        {
            case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                var user = CustomService.UserInformation(desc.SessionId);
                CustomService.DoWhatEverYouWant(user);
            break;
        }   
    }

    private static User UserInformation(int sessionId)
    {
        IntPtr buffer;
        int length;

        var user = new User();

        if (NativeMethods.WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, NativeMethods.WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out buffer, out length) && length > 1)
        {
            user.Name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);

            NativeMethods.WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            if (NativeMethods.WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, NativeMethods.WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out buffer, out length) && length > 1)
            {
                user.Domain = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
                NativeMethods.WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            }
        }

        if (user.Name.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```